# Ошибка ValueError на строке 5: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' при решении задачи

Tags: python

На­пи­ши­те программу, ко­то­рая в по­сле­до­ва­тель­но­сти на­ту­раль­ных чисел опре­де­ля­ет ми­ни­маль­ное чётное число.

Программа по­лу­ча­ет на вход ко­ли­че­ство чисел в последовательности, а затем сами числа. В по­сле­до­ва­тель­но­сти все­гда име­ет­ся чётное число. Ко­ли­че­ство чисел не пре­вы­ша­ет 1000. Введённые числа не пре­вы­ша­ют 30 000.

Программа долж­на вы­ве­сти одно число — ми­ни­маль­ное чётное число.

Вот сама программа:

```
n=int(input())
k=[0]*n
miin=30001
for i in range(len(k)):
     k[i]=int(input())
for i in range(n):
    if k[i]%2==0 and k[i]<miin:
         miin=k[i]
print(miin)
```

Comment: Пользователь вводит не число.

Comment: Приведите пример вводимых данных.

Comment: Можно подробнее?

Comment: Входные данные: 4 3 20 6 8

Comment: @Zessie вам Сергей уже намекнул, что пользователь водит не число. Почитайте, какой тип данных возвращает `input` и подумайте, как может питон перевести строку типа "4 3 20 6 8" в целое.

Comment: @Zessie, а точно числа не отдельно подаются? Если бы они подавались в строке, разделенные пробелом, смысл указывать их количество

Answer (score 2):

В строке №5 функция `input()`, насколько я понял из комментариев, возвращает вам строку из цифр, разделённых пробелом. А вы пытаетесь строку преобразовать в число, поэтому возникает ошибка.

Советую Вам использовать метод `split()`.

Вот пример работающего кода:

```py
n = int(input())
li = input().split()

for x in li:
    num = int(x)
    if num % 2 == 0:
        min_num = num
        break

for x in range(len(li)):
    num = int(li[x])
    if num % 2 == 0 and num < min_num:
        min_num = num

print(min_num)
```

*stdin:*

```html
5
12 3 4 9 8
```

*stdout:*

```html
4
```

Comment: В одну строку функциональщиной: `min(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, map(int, input().split())))`

Comment: @gil9red Прекрасный код! Возьму на заметку. Но, думаю, новичку будет не разобраться :)